# resolving business treatment in service with ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, ngresource

I have an AngularJs application working with components and several modules. I created a plunker example to present my problem [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/LMIG8V894iXARNFYxGbl?p=preview).

I have my NavbarComponent where I declared my Controller where I inject my service called NavbarService.
In the NavbarService, I inject a factory resource to make my Rest call, once this call is made I'm trying to made some treatment on the response before returning it back to the controller, in this example I just apply a simple filter on it, but it doesn't work. If I omit my treatment and return only the categories, the code works and you can visualize a list of two.

I can make my treatment in the controller but this is a bad practice 'cause I believe it should be done in the Service, secondly since it's an asynchronous response I must do something like this to make it work, which is really really ugly:

```
    navbarService.getCategories().$promise.then(function (response) {
                console.log("controller", response[0].category);
                vm.categories = categoryFilter(response[0].category);
            }, function (error) {
               console.log("an error occured");
            });
```

Can someone please guide me through this, I'm out of solutions. Thank you

Comment: you are declaring a local variable in getCatagories function which is not accessible where you passed it in filter function

Comment: @GhulamMohayudin Can you please explain it more? I don't see the problem passing categories variable to categoryFilter since they are on the same level, moreover you can copy paste the code in the CategoryFilter direcly in the service and it still won't work.

Comment: ok let me add an answer for you

Comment: @GhulamMohayudin Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple way is to pass a callback function to service from you component like this

```
 'use strict';

angular.module('navbar').component('appNavbar', {
     templateUrl: "navbar.template.html",
     controller: [ 'navbarService', function appNavbarController(navbarService) {
         var vm = this; 
         navbarService.getCategories(function(data){
             // this will be called when service will get the response and filter function has filtered the response
             vm.categories = data;
         });
      }]
});
```

Now service should be like this

```
 'use strict';

angular.module('navbar').service('navbarService', ['categoryResourceService', 'categoryFilter', function(categoryResourceService, categoryFilter) {
var vm = this;
vm.getCategories = function(callback) {
  categoryResourceService.query(function(response) {
    console.log("[NavbarService] response:", response);
    callback(categoryFilter(response));
  }, function(error) {
    console.log("[NavbarService] error:", error);
  });
  //return vm.categories;  
}

}]);
```

Filter will be like this

```
  'use strict';

  angular.module('navbar').filter('category', function() {
   return function(categories) {
    var categoryIds = ['World'];
    var result = [];
     angular.forEach(categoryIds, function (categoryId) {
     angular.forEach(categories, function (category) {
          if (category.name == categoryId) { 
             console.log("Match"); 
             result.push(category);
          }
      });
    });
   return result;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filter should be like this and it should be called in transformResponse in $resource query instead of service, i hope this will help you

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('navbar').filter('category', function() {
  return function(categories) {
    var categoryIds = ['World'];
    var result = [];
    angular.forEach(categoryIds, function (categoryId) {
        angular.forEach(categories, function (category) {
            if (category.name == categoryId) { 
              console.log("Match"); 
                result.push(category);
            }
        });
    });
    return result;
   };
 });
```

Your categoryResource.service should be like this

```
 angular.module('shared').factory('categoryResourceService', 
   ['$resource','categoryFilter', function($resource, categoryFilter) {
     var provider = "categories.json"; 
     var params = { 
               id: '@id'
           };
     return $resource(provider, params, {
         query: {
           isArray: true,
           method: 'GET',
           params: {},
           transformResponse: function(categories) { 
                var results = categoryFilter(angular.fromJson(categories));  
                console.log("[categoryResourceService] filtered response:", results);
                return results;
           }
        }
    });
 }]);
```

navbar.service should be like this simply

```
 'use strict';

angular.module('navbar')
.service('navbarService', [ 'categoryResourceService', function (categoryResourceService) {
    var vm = this; 
vm.getCategories = function(){
  vm.categories = categoryResourceService.query(function(response){
    console.log("[NavbarService] response:", response); 
  }, function(error){
    console.log("[NavbarService] error:", error);
  });
  return vm.categories;  
 }

}]);
```

And components like this

```
'use strict';

angular.module('navbar').component('appNavbar', {
   templateUrl: "navbar.template.html",
   controller: [ 'navbarService', function appNavbarController(navbarService) {
   var vm = this; 
   vm.categories = navbarService.getCategories();
 }]
});
```

Comment: It didn't work, I updated the plunker with your code :( You can see in the console that the filtered response is an empty array 'cause it tries to apply the filter on the response before getting it from the server, which is really weird since the treatment is in the success callback

Comment: Habchi please use this code and let me know if you face any problem